# how to fix incorrect gnu parallel substring extraction

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I've tried to use substring extraction in bash script mixed with gnu parallel. But below code (simplified from much more complicated case) produces wrong results.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                        

function foo(){                                                    
  echo "${1:0:1} ${1:1:1}" # substring extraction                  
}                                                                  

function bar(){                                                    
  IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "${1}" # string to array conversion
  echo "${array[0]} ${array[1]}"                                   
}                                                                  

export -f foo                                                      
export -f bar                                                      

values=( '12' '34' )                                               

parallel echo $(foo {} ) ::: "${values[@]}"                        
# produces wrong output...                                         
# {} 12                                                            
# {} 34                                                            

parallel echo $(bar {} ) ::: "${values[@]}"                        
# produces wrong output...                                         
# 12                                                               
# 34
```

Could you provide me some hint how can I convince gnu parallel to assume that a variable inside function exists and are not ony brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're missing is that `bash` will do the process substitution `$(foo {} )` *before* it passes arguments to `parallel`. You can see this if you replace `parallel` with `printf "%s\n"`:

```
printf "%s\n" echo $(foo {} ) ::: "${values[@]}"
echo
{
}
:::
12
34
```

Which means your command is equivalent to this:

```
parallel echo { } ::: 12 34
```

And hence why it prints `{ } 12` and `{ } 34`. There is no `{}` here for `parallel` to replace, since `foo` has split it into two separate args, `{` and `}`. So just like `xargs` does when there's no `{}`, `parallel` just tacks on the args to the end of the command, yielding the commands:

```
echo { } 12
echo { } 34
```

To delay the process substitution, you need to wrap it in single quotes:

```
parallel echo '$(foo {} )' ::: "${values[@]}"
```

However, this leads to another problem, because the process spawned by `parallel` won't recognize function `foo`. But you can solve that with `export -f`:

```
export -f foo
parallel echo '$(foo {} )' ::: "${values[@]}"
1 2
3 4
```

Likewise for your `bar` example.

**Edit**: Your `bar` example still prints the same as it did before, but for a different reason. You're trying to `read` the first argument to `bar` into `array`, with `IFS=', '`, but your input doesn't contain any commas (or spaces), so you get an array of one element each time, and `array[1]` expands to nothing.

But if you do this instead, it works (or at least I *think* it does - I'm not sure what your expected output was for this example):

```
values=( "1,2" "3,4" )
parallel echo '$(bar {} )' ::: "${values[@]}"
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: Thank you! Also thanks for pointing out that my second sample with array was wrong from the beginning. It looks that I shouldn't ask question that late in the night!